# Prestashop error while trying to upload image: Composite color model mismatch

Tags: image, upload, prestashop, rgb, photoshop

I am trying to upload an image in my website, using prestashop and I have the following error message:

> Composite: color model mismatch.

I would like to upload a screen shot but I don't know yet how to do it in Stack.
Note: I know the upload limit in Prestashop is 30Mb However my image size in only 7.2 Mb

Here are a serie of uploading test I did if never it can help:

```
1st: Dimension: 10315 × 7049, Size 10,2 MB Result: PASS
2nd: Dimension: 4098 × 4177, Size: 17,9 MB Result: PASS
3rd: Dimension: 21600x10800, Size: 28 MB Result PASS
4th: Dimension: 11846 × 9945, Size: 48,9 MB Result: FAILED (size exceed 30Mb)

5th (The Image I am facing the issue with): 
Dimensions: 5197 × 5197, Size 7.2Mb Result: FAILED
```

So I already know this is not a problem due either to Dimension or Size.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT: You can find an imgur link to see the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7fyQ.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked the colour model of the problem image? Is there anything else in the image that Prestashop may not be able to deal with (file format, alpha channel, layers, etc...)? Your can link to an image on [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and someone can edit your post to embed it.

Comment: The upload limit is defined in the php.ini, NOT in PrestaShop, try checking it.

Comment: Ok but if the upload limit was the problem, none of my images above would been successfully uploaded

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have edited my post to add the image using imgur as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image in is CMYK mode.

Open it in an image editing software (i.e. Photoshop, GIMP, etc...) and change it to RGB mode, then resave it.

This should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

How to set the image in RGB Mode ?

**GIMP** Go to Image → Mode → RGB. (More information on the [Official documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-convert-rgb.html))

**Photoshop** Follow the [Adobe documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/converting-color-modes.html)